# Add two pandas DataFrame with dates and float

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datafames that look like this:

```
         date  bin   value
0 2013-11-01   100   1
1 2013-12-01   200   1

         date  bin   value
0 2013-11-01   100   2
1 2013-12-01   300   5
2 2013-10-01   100   10
```

I would like to find the sum of values for each date and bin, ie the final dataframe should be:

```
         date  bin   value
0 2013-11-01   100   3
1 2013-12-01   200   1
2 2013-12-01   300   15
3 2013-10-01   100   10
```

(indices and order are not important)

When I try:

```
df.add(df2, fill_value = 0)
```

but I get the following error :

```
 TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('O') and dtype('<M8[ns]')
```

I also tried using MultiIndex but I didn't manage to set the double (date, bin) index afterwards...

Any idea how to make it work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed do this with setting those two columns (date and bin) as a multi-index, and then use `add` to specify a fill value (otherwise you get NaNs):

```
In [65]: df1b = df1.set_index(['date', 'bin'])

In [66]: df2b = df2.set_index(['date', 'bin'])

In [67]: df1b + df2b
Out[67]:
                value
date       bin
2013-10-01 100    NaN
2013-11-01 100      3
2013-12-01 200    NaN
           300    NaN

In [68]: df1b.add(df2b, fill_value = 0)
Out[68]:
                value
date       bin
2013-10-01 100     10
2013-11-01 100      3
2013-12-01 200      1
           300      5
```

Another option is to concatenate the two frames, and then group by the two columns date and bin:

```
In [71]: df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)

In [72]: df
Out[72]:
         date  bin  value
0  2013-11-01  100      1
1  2013-12-01  200      1
2  2013-11-01  100      2
3  2013-12-01  300      5
4  2013-10-01  100     10

In [73]: df.groupby(['date', 'bin']).sum()
Out[73]:
                value
date       bin
2013-10-01 100     10
2013-11-01 100      3
2013-12-01 200      1
           300      5
```

The reason for the error message you get above is that apparantly the dtypes of a certain column in `df1` and `df2` is not matching. But in any case, just adding the two dataframes will not work, as you cannot add datetimes.

Comment: `df1b = df1.set_index(['date', 'bin'])` as simple as that! 
Multi-indexing works as exected, thanks for the help!